# What is the convention of numbering carbon atoms in organic molecules?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I am in high school and haven't had a formal chemistry course, however I am fascinated with biology and picked up a biology book more advanced than the one the school is using to read on my own. The book is: [Biology by Peter Raven (2007) ISBN: 0073227390](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0073227390)

I am confused about something in the organic chemistry section.

I don't understand the convention that is used to number carbon atoms in for example, glucose.

In case you don't know what I'm talking about, here is an example: a structural diagram of an a-glucose molecule courtesy of Wikipedia.

[image]

The numbers next to the carbon atoms, I don't understand how they are ordered. Can someone please explain? I know this is an elementary question for most of you, but the help is appreciated.

Comment: Um, you know, IUPAC (The International Union of Pure and Applied Chemistry) writes a 1,500-page reference book to answer this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Glucose occurs as the open chain form aldehyde that determines atom numbering, and as the epimeric cyclic hemiacetal(s) you provided,

[image: Glucose open and cyclic]

The "ether" is a hemiacetal.  C-1's -OH can be up or down.  Either way, it opens and reversibly dehydrates to the aldehyde R-C(=O)H.  Number one atom in a chain is the end that bears the highest total mass.  Double bonds count double their other end atom.  The cyclic form's C=1 also has the largest summed mass attached, two oxygens plus a carbon and a hydrogen.

Comment: So they essentially are numbered from greatest mass to least?

Comment: And why do double covalent bonds cause the other end atom to count twice as much?

Comment: @JasonMills For a double covalent bond, you have 2 bonds, so you count the atom at the end twice. It as if you are counting each bond separately.

Comment: Mass priority traces back to Cahn-Ingold-Prelong (CIP) notation rules for assigning chirality and olefin configuration, etc.  CIP is self-consistent nomenclature not geometry.  L-amino acids alanine and cysteine have opposite CIP chiral labels.

Comment: How does this rule of mass work for purine (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purine)? The number 1 atom (nitrogen) has bonded mass of 36 (3 x carbon) whereas the carbon between 2 nitrogen atoms has bonded mass of 43 (3 x nitrogen + hydrogen).